# eledmac stanza for titlepage

Tags: eledmac

hello world,

one question regarding the Stanza-feature of eledmac. If i try to set a titlepage, were i have to reference more than one line, i can't use separate \pstart and \pend for each line. So I thought of using stanza, but there i fail in inserting a vspace between the author and the title.

```
   \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\beginnumbering
\begin{center}\stanza
\edtext{Laurence Sterne&
The&
Life&
and&
Opinions&
of&
Tristram Shandy,&
Gentleman.}{\lemma{Laurence \ldots Gentleman.}\Afootnote{Blablabla}}\&
\end{center}
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have a space after "Laurence Sterne"?
Thank you! 
Martin

P.S. Just today i set up a new text with eledmac and I am still surprised how well you made it function! Kudos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `\newverse` instead of `&` (§ 6.8 of the handbook).

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
   \usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\beginnumbering
\begin{center}\stanza
\edtext{Laurence Sterne\newverse[\vspace{1em}]
The&
Life&
and&
Opinions&
of&
Tristram Shandy,&
Gentleman.}{\lemma{Laurence \ldots Gentleman.}\Afootnote{Blablabla}}\&
\end{center}
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple! I had seen the \newverse-command, but failed because i added both parentheses in brackets \newverse[\vspace][] and that did not work out... Thank you!

Comment: vspace without argument can't work.